# Find the center (of mass) of a 2D complex polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, centroid

so i'm wondering what the algorithm for finding a shapes center of mass if I have a set of vertices?

Also if it makes the algorithm shorter my **complex polygons are saved as a set of simple convex polygons**, and you can get their vertices.

[image: an image]

I found the above  equation but i don't know how to translate it......

Comment: That's not the equation for center of mass, that's just the average of a bunch of points.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon.

Comment: Homework? If so, you can tag it that way.  Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

In light of new evidence, I firmly believe your given formula is wrong. Allow me to provide a different algorithm. I tried to make it look C++ish, but I'm sure I got some things wrong. If you'd like to nitpick about those, that's fine. If you'd like to downvote on them, I can't stop you, but I'd rather you edit them away to make the post better. :-)

```
// use doubles if appropriate
float xsum = 0.0;
float ysum = 0.0;
float area = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < points.size - 1; i++) {
    // I'm not a c++ guy... do you need to use pointers? You make the call here
    Point p0 = points[i];
    Point p1 = points[i+1];

    double areaSum = (p0.x * p1.y) - (p1.x * p0.y)

    xsum += (p0.x + p1.x) * areaSum;
    ysum += (p0.y + p1.y) * areaSum;
    area += areaSum;
}

float centMassX = xsum / (area * 6);
float centMassY = ysum / (area * 6);
```

Comment: As you suspected this is not the center of mass of the polygon. You can see this by taking a triangle, splitting its base a large number of times, and the average of the vertices will be just off the base, whereas the center of mass is still in the center of the triangle.

Comment: The example I conjured in my mind was a thin, made with the very small side slightly curved, then the curve turned into like a million points. Obviously the center of mass woudln't have changed significantly, since the area didn't change significantly, but the average of the points would be almost entirely the average of points on the small end.

Comment: The average of the corners _will_, however, equal the center of gravity in the special case of a _triangle_. So if you divide your convex polygons into triangles (say, by drawing diagonals from a chosen corner to all other ones), you can then take an average of all the CoG's, weighted by the area of each triangle.

Comment: @Oli thanks for the link on the original post. I've provided an algorithm to match it. On inspection, it appears more intuitive anyway.

Comment: @Henning I thought about that, but if you consider my thin triangle with the split small side... the new triangle could be split into triangles that are all on the small end, causing the center of gravity to also be weighted just like the average of the corners.

Comment: @glowcoder, the corner at the far end counts once for each little triangle that is ajacent to it, which keeps the total balance.

Comment: You've missed the closing line segment in your sum. But otherwise this algorithm is now the same as that at http://shuisman.com/?p=359.

Answer (score 1):

Try the algorithm given [here](http://shuisman.com/?p=359). It will work for convex polygons.

Comment: And polygons with holes in the middle as well.

Comment: This link is dead. Does anyone have a more recent version?

Comment: I think the algorithm was the same as this one: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/centroid.pdf but had a bit of the derivation too.

Answer (score 1):

Te general approach is to split figure into pieces for which the calculation is easier, calculate mass centers for them and combine them: C=sum(C[i]*mass[i])/sum(mass[i])

First of all you should define how mass is distributed in the polygon. Possible (simple) distributions:

1. Concentrated in vertices (uniformly) - the formulae in your question is for this case
2. Uniformly distributed on border of polygon - in this case you should calculate mass center of each line (it's just  the middle of the line), multiply it by line length, add all of them and divide by entire border length
3. Uniformly distributed on area of polygon - simplest for understanding way is to split it to triangles, calculate mass center for each of them, multiply by its area, add all of them, divide by entire area of the polygon

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple average function, roughly like this:

```
template <typename T, typename iterator> T avg(iterator const& begin, iterator const& end) {
  T result;
  size_t size(0);
  for (iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    result += *it;
    size++;
  }
  return result/size;
}
```

Now, assuming your values are in a set, you could do:

```
std::set<double> xs; // assuming your values are in there
double x = avg<double,std::set<double>::iterator>(xs.begin(), xs.end());
```

Without having run it through g++, I'm not sure, which of the template parameters could be inferred automatically.